# How to omit a model formula from the output of mtable

Tags: r, linear-regression

Does anyone know how to exclude from the output of mtable (from the package memisc) the part relative to the model call?
I am building a table to compare 4 models, all of them with over 10 regressors (including interaction terms), and I would like that the 4 formulas are not reported in the results.

```
mtable('Base model' = mod2,
       '+ macro' = mod1.macro,
       '+ struct' = mod1.struct,
       '+ LendMar' = mod1.LendMar,
       summary.stats = c('N','adj. R-squared','AIC','F','p'),
       getSummary=getSummary.lm_sandwich)
```

thanks for your help